# Many passenger config on same domain for many rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I would like to have individuals config for my rails apps on my server, using passenger. How to do it ? For example, I want to have different PassengerPoolIdleTime ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as everything else in Apache: put the declarations in separate per-directory contexts once you make sure that the options you want to change can actually be specified that way. Odds are good you'll want to use your existing VirtualHost blocks for this purpose.

Comment: Except `PassengerPoolIdleTime` is a global config, which can only be specified once. @Erwan, you'll have to read the Passenger User's Guide http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html

Comment: That's exactly why I suggested making sure the options he wants to change can actually be specified that way.